# DLL function name different from exported

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, mex, dumpbin

I´m using a program developed by someone else using c++ and matlab. I have the source code of both, but I don't know what is going on...

Matlab calls a dll generated from c++ using something like this:

```
myCustomCppFunction('param1', 'param2)
```

I was expecting to see *myCustomCppFunction* in the dll exports, but I could not find it.

When I run **dumpbin** command, I receive something like this:

```
dumpbin /exports c:/myCustomCpp.dll
ordinal hint RVA      name
1    0 00001010 myCustomCppFunctionWithADifferentName
```

So,

**myCustomCppFunctionWithADifferentName != myCustomCppFunction**

The DLL is exporting a function name that is different than the function name that my matlab is calling. And I'm not talking about mangled names, both names are 100% different, like 'apple' and 'banana'. :-)

Somehow, everything works fine! but how?!?

In Matlab, I also ran **which** command that confirms to me that the function called is from the DLL I´m investigating....

```
>> which myCustomCppFunctionWithADifferentName
>> c:/myCustomCpp.dll
```

any clues?

Comment: Can you please the *actual* names, your function name, and the name in the DLL?

Comment: functionName as appear in dumpbin :    "carWalk"
functionName that Matlab is calling :       "iterateOverRoad"
DLL name :    "iterateOverRoad"

Comment: does a DLL have a "entry point"?  Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, DLLs have [a "main" function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your [mex](/questions/tagged/mex) tag, I'm not sure your dealing with a MEX file.

The name of a MEX file (a DLL) is not related to the name of the exported function.  The exported function in a MEX file is:

```
mexFunction
```

In Windows, there is still a `DLLMain`, but **MATLAB looks for `mexFunction`**.

So this is what happens:

```
>> myMEXFunction()  % looks for myMEXFunction.mexw64 (or whatever extension)
```

If myMEXFunction.mexw64 has `mexFunction` exported, you are in business.

Note that `mexFunction` is *declared* in `mex.h` as `extern "C"` (if you are compiling a .cpp), you just *define* it in your source.  So it will always be undecorated.

However, your myCustomCpp.dll does not export `mexFunction`, so perhaps you are not talking about a MEX file?  Also, what makes me more uncertain if you are talking about a MEX file is the strange result you get with `which`.  Is your MATLAB source (`myCustomCppFunction`) actually using `loadlibrary` or `calllib` to operate with the DLL?  If `myCustomCppFunction()` loaded a non-MEX DLL in this fashion, then what you are showing makes sense.